# Converting varchar to varbinary

Tags: sql, sql-server

Trying to understand varchar to varbinary conversion, when i run below query

```
select CAST(3 as varbinary(512))
```

result is 0x00000003
but if I cast 0x00000003 back to varchar using below query then result is ' '

```
cast(0x00000003 as varchar)
```

Below query actually gives me result as 3.

```
select cast(0x33 as varchar)
```

I tried it with Convert also, but results are same. I would appreciate if anyone can explain this behavior.

Comment: if you case `select cast(0x00000003 as int)` then you will get 3

Answer (score 6):

`3` is not a `varchar`. It is an int. So you see the binary format of a signed int stored in [twos complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

`'3'` is a `varchar`

```
select CAST('3' as varbinary(512))
```

Returns `0x33` (decimal 51 which is the [ASCII code](http://www.asciitable.com/) for `3`)

Answer (score 0):

You should convert `binary` to `int` and then cast it as a `varchar` to get the same number back.

```
select cast(cast(CAST(3 as varbinary(512)) as int) as varchar)
```